# Loggly not working via Winston on Pi

Tags: linux, node.js, raspbian, winston, loggly

I have an IoT project running on a Raspberry Pi 2 using the Raspbian Jessie OS.

It's a web server running in NodeJS (v4) and I'm using Winston to log to Loggly's logging service. All works well when the project is kicked off via `npm start` from terminal (when running as 'pi' or via sudo -s). However, when the project starts on boot, the logging doesn't work and I can't work out why.

To start the project on boot I created a etc/init.d script. The project starts and serves traffic, everything works great except for logging. I can't see any errors (though not having logging doesn't help). This is how I start my project from inside my etc/init.d script:

```
/usr/bin/node /var/www/curtains/server.js
```

I'm using winston: https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston and winston-loggly: https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-loggly.

Any ideas why, when the process is started on bootup the logging doesn't work?

Adding winston initialization code as requested:

```
var winston = require('winston');
require('winston-loggly');

 winston.add(winston.transports.Loggly, {
    token: "<snip>",
    subdomain: "<snip>",
    tags: ["tag", ip.address()],
    json:true
});

winston.log('info',"Server.js starting up");
```

Comment: Do you have any relative paths in your log configuration? Also it would be helpful to see your winston initialization from `server.js` can you add this code?

Comment: Added initialization code from server.js - there is no log configuration that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 2):

When you run `npm start`, node will look for a scripts object in your package.json file, and run the commands associated with the `start` key.

In your `init.d` script you are not running `npm start`, but instead just running node and passing your `server.js` file as the first argument (which will run that file).

Most likely, something in your `start` script is needed in order to run your logging correctly. To solve this, you can either:

- In your `init.d` script, `cwd` to your project root and then run `npm start`.
- Look in your `package.json` to see what else your `start` script is doing, and add the equivalent to your `init.d` script.

Comment: Sadly this didn't make any difference. I also tried running my local project in the same way, e.g. `/usr/local/bin/node /Users/Me/Documents/Projects/server.js` and that worked fine, logging as expected. There's no 'start' script in my package.json either - great suggestions but this doesn't look like this is what's wrong.

Comment: I updated the /etc/init.d script to change working directory and npm start. I then used `sudo -s` to run the script manually, e.g. `/etc/init.d/myscript start`. This works great, logging is good. However, when the script executes on reboot... nothing :(